# saving polynomial model , doesn't save polynomial degree

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I deal with polynomial degree when I want to save a polynomial model, sicne this info is not being saved!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "a": np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 1000),
        "b": np.random.uniform(10.0, 14.0, 1000),
        "c": np.random.uniform(100.0, 1000.0, 1000)})



def data():
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val  = train_test_split(df.iloc[:, :2].values,
                                                       df.iloc[:, 2].values,
                                                       test_size=0.2,
                                                       random_state=1340)
       
    return X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val


X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = data()


poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)

poly_reg_model = LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, y_train)



poly_model = joblib.dump(poly_reg_model, 'themodel')

y_pred = poly_reg_model.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X_val))

themodel = joblib.load('themodel')
```

Now, if I try to predict:

`themodel.predict(X_val)`, I am receiving:

`ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 6 is different from 2)`

I have to do:

`pol_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)`
`themodel.predict(pol_feat.fit_transform(X_val))`

in order to work.
So, how can i store this info in order to be able to use the model for prediction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pickle trained PolynomialFeatures also:

```
# train and pickle
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
poly_reg_model = LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, y_train)

joblib.dump(poly_reg_model, 'themodel')
joblib.dump(poly_reg, 'poilynomia_features_model')

# load and predict
poilynomia_features_model = joblib.load('poilynomia_features_model')
themodel = joblib.load('themodel')

X_val_prep = poilynomia_features_model.transform(X_val)
predictions = themodel.predict(X_val_prep)
```

But better will wrap all the steps in the single [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('poilynomia', PolynomialFeatures()), 
                           ('lr', LinearRegression())])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline.predict(X_val)
```